# How to retrieve dynamic values from Api request response

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I am receiving a dynamic response from my API, but I do not know how to retrieve it like inside data the fields are changing:

```
{
    "status": "ERROR",
    "data": {
        "email-common": "This email already exists."
    }
}
```

Another time it might look like this:

```
{
    "status": "ERROR",
    "data": {
        "password": "passwords do not match"
    }
}
```

I know the code in Java but in flutter I don't know how to do it. Idea can be get from this Java code

```
JSONObject data = result.getJSONObject("data");
Iterator<String> keys = data.keys();

while (keys.hasNext()) {
     String key = keys.next();
     Log.d("myTag", data.get(key).toString());
}
```

If I do it for password then it's throwing errors, for the other one my question is whatever values there is I can retrieve it (dynamic retrieval)

```
 Future<Map> getJson() async {
     String apiUrl = 'http://3.127.255.230/rest_ci/api/customers';

     Map<String,String> headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json','Authorization':'mykeyyyy'};
     final msg = jsonEncode({
         "username":"tesstestt123",
         "email":"khansdf@gmail.com",
         "password":"testtest",
         "confirm_password":"testtest",
     });

     http.Response response = await http
        .post(apiUrl,
               headers: headers,
               body: msg, );

     return json.decode(response.body); // returns a List type
}

void khan() async {
    getJson();
    String _body = "";

    Map _data = await getJson();

    _body = (_data['status']);
    print(_data);

    if (_body == 'ERROR') {
       setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
      print("$_data");
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (c) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("oops"),
              content: Text(_data['data']['password']),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: Text("Close"),
                )
              ],
            );
          });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart has built-in support to [decode a JSON string](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-convert/json-constant.html). Like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = json.decode(yourJSONString);
```

You can access any values inside this map like you would do in Java

```
print(jsonMap["status"]);
print(jsonMap["data"]["password"]);
```

If you just always want to access the values inside "data" without knowing they keys you could iterate them:

```
Map<String, dynamic> dataMap = jsonMap["data"];
dataMap.keys.forEach((k) {
    print(k);
    print(dataMap[k]);
});
```

Comment: i updated my question i can retrieve a single value like "password": "passwords doesnot match" but my questions is ,it is changing like if user enter an email which already exist the response will be different

Comment: You can either return an identifier in the JSON data to be able to identify what type of response it is. Or you can check the Map for the presence of certain keys you expect at one response, but not from the other.

Comment: sorry , i am new to flutter i won't be able to understand you. i want to show the data whatever in the "data" json object as i already told you its varying. it can be anything there is alot of possibilites here so whatever is it i want to display it,thanks in advance

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please see if this helps. You can always just iterate the keys in the nested dataMap and thus do not need to know the keys beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Basically: you can use a function to fetch data and use it in future builder.

Fetching data:

```
Future<dynamic> getData() async{
    http.Response response =  await http.get("url");
    return jsonDecode(response.body);
  }
```

Using in Future Builder:

```
FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
                        future: getData(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Text(
                              'There was an error..',
                            );
                          }
                          else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return Text(snapshot.data['id'])
}})
```

Or you can use it as var and write directly

```
jsonDecode(response.body)['results']
```

Comment: i updated my question i can retrieve a single value like "password": "passwords doesnot match" but my questions is ,it is changing like if user enter an email which already exist the response will be different